# Hydrocyclone effectiveness vs. absolute pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-dynamics, pressure, cyclones

Some sources say that higher pressure in hydrocyclones implies better performance it leads to a finer filtration. But why?

Is it because water is almost incompressible and the particles can be pressured and their density increased?

Comment: Are you sure your sources say pressure, not pressure loss?

Comment: Yes only pressure. Pressure loss is clear. Higher pressure loss = higher tangential speed = higher centrifugal force = better separation. PS: THX Fred for grammar correction.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide references/links to the sources you mention.

Comment: It's in different language and it was misunderstanding - the part with higher pressure is about waste reservoir flushing. (Higher pressure = faster flushing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the word **performance** might be misleading since a connection to *pressure loss* is quite reasonable. However, in this context I guess **performance** is connected to the filtration.

Using higher pressure implies in deed a higher pressure loss but it also results in a higher circumferential velocity. Since the main working principle of a hydrocyclone is to divide a solid-liquid suspensions by density a higher circumferential velocity will increase the radial acceleration. Since small particles will encounter higher drag du to their smaller Reynoldsnumber it will take longer for them to travel to the outside wall (based on [Svarovsky (1981)](https://books.google.de/books?id=8dj5IJbEwu4C&lpg=PP2&ots=3jH8p-NrNE&lr&pg=PR4#v=onepage&q&f=false),  residence time theory ).

[image: hydrocyc]

In order to have a *better* filter a higher radial acceleration is needed which (all other things kept equal) asks for higher pressure to produce higher circumferential velocities.

Comment: The question was based on misunderstanding (see comment above). Higher pressure provide better flushing of waste from reservoir.